# re-direct URL with google +

Tags: google

I have a WP plugin that is throwing up an error after I go to authorise my account to link up with the Client ID and Client Secret details set up in Google +..

This is the error

Error:redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://nutribalance.net/wp-content/plugins/paged_social_lockdown/lib/google/plus/ did not match a registered redirect URI

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks, David

Comment: This is the request details in the plug in:    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
    response_type=code
    redirect_uri=http://nutribalance.net/wp-content/plugins/paged_social_lockdown/lib/google/plus/
    access_type=offline
    display=page
    prompt=consent
    client_id=762188472537.apps.googleusercontent.com